# JSON.parse error

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

I am trying to parse a result I get through a websocket.

```
sock.onmessage = function(e) {
    log(e.data);
}

function log(m) {       
    var obj = JSON.parse(m);
}
```

But I get the error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

On the server it says in python

```
def broadcast(self):

  response = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:8001/json?as_text=1')
  data = response.read();

  for c in self.clients:
     c.sendMessage(data)
```

Comment: can you log `m` ? This would probably say why it can't be parsed.

Comment: do an alert of data and see if it comes through as `[Object object]`

Comment: An alert of m returns the json. An alert of obj return [Object object]

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to do something like that

data= JSON.stringify(response)

Comment: This returns AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stringify'

Comment: Than according to @Newcoma make an alert what does it show it need to be shown [Object object]